# Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Nowadays I am trying to understand LDA. I have read a lot but something is missing.

For instance, when I have a vector with three different variables (buy order, sell order, volume) respectively: [14,34,23]  And have over 12 Million records per each customer.

I want to profile them by using LDA. How should I organize my data? What will be the analysing process? Furthermore, how will I interpret the results? I could not find any numerical (not topic modeling) examples.

Thanks in advance..

Teitia

Comment: Just to mention that I've often seen LDA used to mean linear discriminant analysis. TLAs can cause (minor) confusion. (TLA = three-letter abbreviation, naturally.)

Comment: Also see LDA = Longitudinal Data Analysis

Answer (score 3):

even if my answer is months after you posted your question, hope it can help others,
I have also recently started to learn about LDA, there is this video that can help [Here](http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_blei_tm/#c8301), by the author of the paper.
and if you are using R, you can use the package LDA.

If I got you question right, you want to know, for each cluster what are the sell and buy orders that a repeated a lot? or you want to know what type of products he buys a lot?

we suppose you want to know the list of the products, and suppose he did 1 million purchase and for each purchase he has a list of elements.

You can first create vocabulary list, which is just a list that contains all the possible elements names (you can do it as the union of names of the elements in your 1 million purchase)
Then create a list of 1 million matrix, each list represent a purchase and in each list and the frequency of appearance, write the index of the element in the vocabulary (if using LDA package, it should be 0-based).

And they for example you say you want to get 5 categories of the elements that occur together.
Here is a sample code in R (I didn't test it, but it should work)

```
elem_vocab<-c("Elem1","Elem2","Elem3","Elem4","Elem5","Elem6","Elem7")
purchases<-list();
purchases[[1]]<-t(matrix(c( c(0,1,3,4), c(2,1,1,4) ),nrow=4,ncol=2))
purchases[[2]]<-t(matrix(c( c(0,2,3,5), c(1,6,1,5) ),nrow=4,ncol=2))
purchases[[3]]<-t(matrix(c( c(2,1,3,4), c(4,1,9,3) ),nrow=4,ncol=2))
purchases[[4]]<-t(matrix(c( c(6,1,5,4), c(3,10,3,4) ),nrow=4,ncol=2))

library(lda);
ldaRes<-lda.collapsed.gibbs.sampler(document=purchases,vocab=elem_vocab,
       K=2,num.iterations=200,alpha=0.1,eta=0.1,compute.log.likelihood=T,burnin=100)

topElem<-top.topic.words(ldaRes$topics,5,by.score=T)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sirus.I mean, let's assume an investor did a transaction on date x. It was a purchase with amount of 5000 and 200 volume. I will define my vector like [5000,200,1]. (1 presents type of interaction as purchase) No, how can we organize our codes? Hope, my definition is clear.